# Retrieving a timestamp from Azure Website Server C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have read over several posts on this and cannot really come up with the write solution.

I want to get the time from the server save it to a file then compare it to a timer.  I have this all coded and working except for the issue of the time on the PC and Server being different by several seconds.  Seconds matter in this application.  So, the best way to resolve this would be to do the following

Here is what I want to do:

1. Ping my Azure Website server to get its current time (port 13 is NOT open)
2. Write that time to a file on the local PC.
3. Send that file back with all the other information I am collecting.

I am current using SteamWriter on the PC like this:

```
SR.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-5).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"));
```

And at the Server like this:

```
string currenttime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-5).ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
```

This works to a point but the seconds is up to 26 seconds difference.

The way to resolve this in my application is grab the server time, post in my file and send it back and read it.

I hope this makes sense and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why does the local PC time matter at all?

Comment: It doesn't if I can get the server time in a local PC file. That is what I am trying to do.  But I do need the time from the Server at the time of the event.

Comment: Your current question says the times differ... and your comment says you don't care. So... what exactly is your question?

Comment: Why don't you just record the time of the upload event on the server when it happens?

Comment: Because I don't want the time of the upload, I want the time of an event on the local PC but I want it to be synchronized with the server.  I am not looking for someone to talk me out of doing it this way, I just want to pull the sever of the time down.

Comment: Then maybe describe your problem? You can pull the current time from the server in 20 Million ways, what *exactly* is your problem with doing it?

Comment: I am using an Azure server and cannot figure out to how to pull the time down at the time of the event...I think the problem is described properly in the onset.

Comment: So you are using ASP.NET and you have no clue how to write a controller that sends the current time back to the client?

Comment: I don't want the server to send the time to the client, I want the client to request the server time at the time of the event and log it locally

Comment: I will VTC as too broad. You seem to have no idea how client and server might communicate. That's fine, nobody is born with that knowledge, but you need to read a book about it, it's too broad for our Q&A format, we cannot explain ASP.NET or WCF to you in a nutshell here.

Answer (score 0):

Using several sources of *current time* in the distributed application leads to out of synchronization.

When you have client time and server time, or application time and SQL time, or a set of times of microservices; then all of these times can different in a second or two.

You may redesign you application. F.e. the server always creates the empty file and sends it to the client, and the client stores it with server timestamp.

Or you can send client time to server, and server stores both itself time and the client time.

Comment: I need to have the time logged at the time of the event on the PC and I need the time on PC and server sync'd at all time.  That is impossible so if I grab the Server Time at the time of the event so when I send that timestamp back with the other information it can have an accurate timer.

Comment: Mark, what you said about the server creating an empty file and storing with a timestamp is exactly what I am trying to figure how to do...ideas?

Comment: As far as I understand you have a few clients with local event and you want merge all these event in a single server table. Or not? If you really don't need to order events in a single sequence, you can store their local timestamps on the server. If you need to order them, you don't have store them locally cause only single server can order events correctly. Just send the event to the server every time it occurs.

Comment: Mark,  see my post about having the server write out a time file every second then reading then downloading that file when an event happens.  It works as I need it to.  Your comment about creating an empty file got me thinking about this eventual solution,...thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I did figure out a solution that works.  I have the server writing a time file out every second.  When the event happens at the client I am using Webclient to download the file then reading that file to insert into my event file.  This works really well.  I do have a 'file in use' issue every once in a while but I can overcome that issue.